# Proving $3$ similar factorization formulas

Tags: factoring

> **Question:** How would you prove the following formulas:

\begin{align*} & a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum_{k=1}^na^{n-k}b^{k-1}\qquad\qquad\qquad[\text{Always}]\\ & a^n-b^n=(a+b)\sum_{k=1}^n-(-1)^ka^{n-k}b^{k-1}\qquad[\text{If n is even}]\\ & a^n+b^n=(a+b)\sum_{k=1}^n-(-1)^ka^{n-k}b^{k-1}\qquad[\text{If n is odd}]\end{align*}

---

I find these formulas incredibly interesting and wonder how they came up with them in the first place. I don't know where to begin in the proof.

Note that I *do* understand that you can multiply out the right hand side and see if both sides give an identity, but I don' really consider that a proof because it doesn't tell me how the person got to this formula in the first place.

I *do* realize that the third formula is the same as the second formula for when $b=-b$. So if I can prove the first and second formulas, then simply replacing $b$ with its negated version wil give you formula $3$.

Comment: Multiplying out the right-hand side really is the way to prove these. The formulas can be obtained by polynomial long division (but since $n$ is unknown, you can't really perform the whole long division, but you can start and notice a pattern and write down the formula that way).

Comment: @kccu So multiplying both sides of a formula down into simplest terms is considered a proof?? Wow... I didn't know that...

Comment: Yes, algebraic manipulation is a perfectly valid proof.

Comment: Induction on $n$, maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These probably were discovered,
like many results,
by looking at results
for small $n$
and seeing how they could
be generalized.

For example,
looking at
$a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$
and
$a^3-b^3 = (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)
$
would suggest the first formula.

$a^3+b^3
=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)
$
would suggest the third formula.

As for your second formula,
it is wrong.
If we put
$n=2$ it says
$a^2-b^2
=(a-b)(-\sum_{k=1}^2 (-1)^ka^{2-k}b^{k-1})
=(a-b)(-(-a+b))
=(a-b)(a-b)
$
which is false.

Comment: Oops. It's supposed to be$$a^n-b^n=(a+b)\sum_{k=1}^n -(-1)^k a^{n-k}b^{k-1}$$